# CSS overflow breaks click events on Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, css, media-queries, dolphin-browser

I feel like I am missing something fundamental.

On:

Samsung's Galaxy Tab 10.1 (might be tru on other Andoid devices - not sure)
Dolphin or built-in 'default' browser
Any block element styled with overflow: auto or overflow-y auto, to get a vertical scrollbar causes that div to act like it isn't even in the event tree when a child is clicked.

For example. I have something like this:

```
<div id="a">
    <ul>
        <li>one</li>
        <li>two</li>
    <ul>
</div>
```

If ul is styled to have overflow:auto then clicking on 'one' or 'two' fires the event on #a - it's as if the ul/li's aren't even there. In portrait mode all is well. I can literally tilt the tablet 90 degrees to make it work, make it fail, etc.

I still need to simplify this in fiddler but you can see the effect by going here:

Since it is both browsers it must be my problem!?!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

This appears to be a variation on [this problem.](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2118)