# document.elementFromPoint(x,y) - pure JavaScript alternative?

Tags: javascript, android, polyfills

On some Android devices (native browser) `elementFromPoint()` is [broken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11267961/css-overflow-breaks-click-events-on-galaxy-tab) when using the  `overflow:auto` CSS property in many situations, so that it returns a parent (the one with `overflow:auto`) of the correct element.

Is there a complete, fast replacement/polyfill for that function that resembles the native function, but is written in JavaScript?

I am aware of the `offsetXXXXX` properties, but when adding scrolling and position/overflow CSS settings things are becoming complex...

Comment: This is still an issue in 2020! If you were to test in Chrome on most popular Android device (chrome 61) elementFromPoint() just doesn't work.